# Series of sinus for prime numbers

Tags: convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Is there a real number $\epsilon>0, \,\epsilon<\pi$ such that 
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\operatorname{sin}(\epsilon\cdot p_k)
$$
converges? Where $p_k$ is the kth primenumber.

Comment: If $0 < \epsilon < \pi$, then I don't think the terms even tend to $0$.

Comment: @TonyK: No, at least not for rational numbers. But couldn't there be an irrational number? A number constructed for the purpose?

Comment: I don't know $-$ that's why I said "I don't think". But perhaps you should decide on this question before you proceed to the harder question of the infinite sum.

Comment: @TonyK: Yes, I was unfocused while using the computer for tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, if $0 < \epsilon < \pi$, the terms $\sin(\epsilon p_k)$ don't even tend to zero:

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\sin(\epsilon p_k) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Thanks to [Yitang Zhang](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2014/179-3/p07) (and the follow-up work of [Terry Tao's PolyMath cohorts](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes)), we now know that there exists an integer $G \le 246$ such that the gap between consecutive primes is equal to $G$ infinitely often. Let $q_k$ be the $k$th prime such that $q_k+G$ is also prime. Then $\sin(\epsilon q_k)$ and $\sin(\epsilon(q_k+G))$ both tend to zero as $k \to \infty$.

But $\sin(\epsilon(q_k+G)) = \sin(\epsilon q_k)\cos(\epsilon G)+\cos(\epsilon q_k)\sin(\epsilon G)$, which tends to $\sin(\epsilon G)$. So $\sin(\epsilon G)$ must be zero, which means that $\epsilon G = N\pi$ for some integer $N < G$ (because $\epsilon < \pi$).

So $\epsilon$ is a rational multipe of $\pi$, i.e. $\epsilon=\pi s/t$ with $s,t$ coprime and $t > 1$. And for any prime $p > t$, the fractional part of $ps/t$ is at least $1/t$ and at most $1-1/t$. So $\sin(\epsilon p)$ is bounded away from $0$ by an amount $\sin(\pi/t)$.

Comment: How come $\operatorname{sin}(\epsilon q_k),\operatorname{sin}(\epsilon(q_k+G))\to 0$? Are you making an asumption for $\epsilon$?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I added a sentence to the start of the second paragraph.